# Is it necessary for the Ecto schema and the SQL database to have the same foreign keys?

Tags: eclipse, phoenix-framework

When I use the `references` keyword to generate schema I notice that in the actual database the corresponding column does not have list the column as a foreign key.

E.g. lets say we call (in our console):
`mix phx.gen.html Multimedia Video videos user_id:references:users \
url:string title:string description:text`

This generates a table in pgsql which looks like this:
[image]

Notice how user_id doesn't have [FK] in the column name. And looking at the properties of there are no foreign keys too.

My question is: is it necessary to have the ecto schema and sql database indicate the same foreign keys? In Phoenix, we use `belongs_to :user, Rumbl.Accounts.User` in the schema for videos to indicate a foreign key. But looking at the database you can't really infer that.

Comment: When you cast `mix phx.gen.<whatever>` is _doesn't_ generate any tables. Tables are generated when you run migrations with `mix ecto.migrate`. So the source of truth here is not CLI commands but 1) schema migration(s) and 2) PG table specification (not some visual representation but the output of `\d <table_name>`). Could you provide both?

Comment: I'm not sure how to show 1 and 2. `\d` doesn't work on console. Also, the question is more of a theoretical one. Because everything works fine because the schema treats the `user_id` as a foreign key. It's just not explicitly written when looking at the actual sql db through pgsq4.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**
It is not strictly necessary to have the relationships defined on the database level. Ecto associations will work even if the database has no idea tables are related and when no foreign key indices and constraints were defined.

Having said that, relations, properly defined on the database level have many benefits, such as referential integrity, better performance, and added functionality available when changes are applied to the data. Therefore, although it is possible to skip these, it is hardly recommended.

Now some explanations about the database objects you see. Here are the migration and the schema, generated by the command you mentioned,

> mix phx.gen.html Multimedia Video videos user_id:references:users url:string title:string description:text

```
  # in priv/repo/migrations/<timestamp>_create_videos.exs

  def change do
    create table(:videos) do
      add :url, :string
      add :title, :string
      add :description, :text
      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:videos, [:user_id])
  end

  # in lib/app/multimedia/video.ex

  schema "videos" do
    field :description, :string
    field :title, :string
    field :url, :string
    field :user_id, :id

    timestamps()
  end
```

Note that the migration includes the `references` definition while the schema does not mention any relation to `users`. As you pointed out, the schema does need to be modified to include the association `belongs_to :user` (`User` schema on the other side also needs to be updated).

Nevertheless, the table definition resulted from this migration does indeed include the foreign key specification:

```
shell> psql -h localhost -U postgres -d db_name
psql> \d videos

# output
                                         Table "public.videos"
   Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default
-------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('videos_id_seq'::regclass)
 url         | character varying(255)         |           |          |
 title       | character varying(255)         |           |          |
 description | text                           |           |          |
 user_id     | bigint                         |           |          |
 inserted_at | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at  | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "videos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "videos_user_id_index" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "videos_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

You can get this output from `psql`, the command line postgres client. Other (GUI) clients out there may or may not implement support for everything you need to know about your database, so it is best to use the definitive toolset as @KonstantinStrukov [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408019/is-it-necessary-for-the-ecto-schema-and-the-sql-database-to-have-the-same-foreig#comment99528892_56408019).